# Can someone explain this construction?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, idiom, grammar-identification, renaissance-latin

I'm trying to read the opening (Latin) poem of Robert Burton's *The Anatomy of Melancholy*.

[Here's a link to the page](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/moa/ACM8939.0001.001/15?rgn=full%20text;view=image) in the edition.

The title is *Democritus Junior ad Librum Suum*. For some reason Burton refers to himself as "Democritus Junior".

The poem starts like this:

> Vade libur, qualis, non ausim dicere, fœlix
> Te nisi fœlicem fecerit Alma dies.
> Vade tamen quocunque lubet, quascunque per oras,
> Et Genium Domini fac imitere tui.
> I blandas inter Charites, mystamque saluta
> Musarum quemvis, si tibi lector erit.

Apart from wondering

- whether *libur* is some strange vocative of *liber*
- why *alma* is capitalised
- what *mystam* might mean, and whether it is masculine (going with *quemvis*)

**... the main thing I'm puzzled by is this expression "*Et Genium Domini fac imitere tui*"**

The thing is, it is remarkably close to the French or Italian construction meaning "to cause someone to do something" i.e. "*...fais imiter le génie de ton maître*".

But *imitere*, with an "e", is not *imitare*, the infinitive. And is in fact the 2nd sing. subjunctive passive present. So on the face of it it appears to mean "make (act such) that you may be imitated". I'm trying to get my head around this because if we have a passive verbal form, how come we can have a noun in the accusative?

Is it the case that this "*fac imitere*" construction sort of becomes an "honorary active form", thus justifying the accusative "*Genium*"? Or have I got it completely wrong? Is this a quite common construction, or rare?

NB there is a 17th Century English translation of this poem in this edition, possibly by Burton himself. But it is such a loose, flowery translation it doesn't really help me answer the question.

If the consensus among experts is that *imitere* is in fact a misspelling of *imitare*, that would be a very useful thing to know.

Comment: If possible, please include a link or image of the exact edition you're using. That way we can verify "libur" for "liber."

Comment: Given other spelling oddities, like foelix for (presumably) fēlix, I wouldn't be too surprised if libur and imitere were similarly unorthodox spellings.

Comment: Link to page added.

Comment: @Draconis, foelix is a common early modern hypercorrection. Authors of this time were aware that in many words, classical "ae" and "oe" had been contracted to "e" in the middle ages. Sometimes they incorrectly "restored" a longer reading. "Caeterum" is another common hypercorrection.

Comment: @Kingshorsey Also, if I remember right, hasn't "coeli" (for caelī) become standard in some of the liturgy?

Comment: @Draconis Yep, you even see it in 18th century texts every so often.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

libur pro "liber" false positum (cf. [hanc editionem](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Anatomy_of_melancholy_what_it_is_wit/PWc_AAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Te%20nisi%20foelicem%20fecerit%20Alma%20dies&pg=PR15&printsec=frontcover))

Alma dies = dies propitius, faustus, secundus

mystam (cf. Graece μύστης) = sacerdotem

fac imitere - imitor is a deponent verb, so all its finite forms are passive though active (or middle) in meaning. Thus, it can take an accusative object. As you correctly surmised through analogy with French/Italian, *fac* plus a subjunctive is an imperative form: *Make sure you imitate*.

Comment: Thanks for explaining all 4 points. Wow.

Comment: I'd only add that *mystam* does go with *quemvīs,* but the latter isn't masculine, it's common gender, non-exclusive. Why he chose the common gender pronoun when the Muses are all female is another question. One good possibility is to avoid confusion with *quamvīs* 'however much; albeit'.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian I interpreted mystam Musarum as someone who cultivates or is devoted to good literature, i.e., a learned person, whom Burton hopes will be a reader of this book. Humanists invented all kinds of congratulatory titles for their readers. BTW Anatomy of Melancholy is absolutely wild in its freeform adoption of classical literature into an almost stream-of-consciousness narrative.

Comment: Oh, right, of course it's *mysta Mūsārum* - I thought it referred to the Muses appositionally, probably due to the line-break/syntax.